# Refinement Panel Category Showing Wrong Value In Header

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, refinement-panel, refiner

I have a refinement panel that is supposed to have the "Tags" category renamed as "Subject Keywords". However, when I do that, not only does it not show "Subject Keywords", it actually shows the name of a site column which I did not specify. Is this a known behavior or what?

I renamed the "Tags" category via the XML file that configures the category.

Please let me know if you require more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, you did unchecked the "Use Default Configuration" checkbox right?

Make sure the XML in the Filter Category Definition does not contain twice the definition of the filter. See here for an example, just to be sure http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-search-refinement-panel-options/ (few more links also present at the bottom of the article http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/10/custom-refinement-filters-in-sharepoint-2010/) which exemplifies.

In addition to that, Managed Metadata based refiners are usually added automatically with regards to the content being searched and results presented. So if you have such as situation, maybe it would be good to not add it in the 1st place.